# Get Non Proxy Classes From Proxy Classes, by keeping Proxy and Lazy Load Enabled in Entity Framework.

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-relationship, proxy-classes

I am using EF with proxy and lazy load enabled. But for some process I need to get the actual non proxy classes. I have used "proxy.GetType();" etc. But all in vain. Can you please help me to get the non proxy classes?

Thanks..

```
Code:

  public virtual Type GetRealType(object proxy)
        {
           return proxy.GetType();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that type out of your Context class:

```
public virtual Type GetRealType(object proxy)
{
    return MyContext.GetObjectType(proxy.GetType());
}
```

Other info about proxy types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/data/jj592886.aspx